# Saving progress while Cycles is rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Let's say, I am rendering an animation and I am half-way in (frame-wise). I would like to save what has been computed so far and resume the rendering later. I can see that the generated .avi file is updating as the rendering goes, but I am not sure if Blender is smart enough to bootstrap from this file and concatenate more frames later.

Is it possible to save the progress of rendering using Cycles engine? If so, how?

Cheers

Edit:
Running on Blender 2.82

Comment: Render as image sequence, this way you can pause anytime....

Comment: @brockmann, I guess there is no way to do so for the already rendered stack of frames? As in, while the animation rendering is running, converting what has been rendered to images.

Comment: No, unfortunately. Encoding to mp4 or mov directly should be removed from the menu, bad idea in general...

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for your suggestion.